# scriptish in firefox 42.0b3 call jquery fail

Tags: jquery, firefox, scriptish

I don't know what happen, seems scriptish(nightly 0.1.13pre) in firefox 42.0b3 can't load JQuery now, could someone help me.
here is the origin code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             test
// @name           test
// @version        1.0
// @namespace
// @author
// @description
// @include       *
// ==/UserScript==
console.log($);
```

After search I found maybe use @require can solve this problem, so modified my code.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             test
// @name           test
// @version        1.0
// @namespace
// @author
// @description
// @include        /*
// @require       https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
console.log($);
```

here is the error message in firebug

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
1> JS frame :: resource://scriptish/utils/Scriptish_evalInSandbox.js :: Scriptish_evalInSandbox :: line 38
2> JS frame :: resource://scriptish/utils/Scriptish_injectScripts.js :: Scriptish_injectScripts :: line 121
3> JS frame :: resource://scriptish/manager.js :: listener :: line 125
4> native frame :: <unknown filename> :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 0
```

Comment: Scriptish has not been maintained for about a year, plus.  Meanwhile, Firefox has made significant changes to script handling and sandboxing. ... You may have to switch back to Greasemonkey or fork/patch Scriptish yourself.